# How to interact with UI from a different class

Tags: java, android

I would like to update my UI from a different class. I am familiar with `runOnUiThread()` method, but don't know how to implement it in this scenario?

```
public class UploadAct extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    }

    //my code and functions would go here
}
```

Then, my UploadData class

```
public class UploadData extends UploadAct {
    public void doSomethig(){
        printThis("I want to print this message to the UI");
    }

    public void printThis(String messsage) {
        final String mess = message;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mess,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // I want this to display on the main thread
                txt_upload.setText(mess);// and this also
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `BroadcastReceiver`

```
// define a Broadcast Intent Action in String resources
<string name="broadcast_id">MY_BROADCAST_ID</string>

// register receiver in constructor/onCreate()
MyBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
myIntentFilter.addAction(context.getString(R.string.broadcast_id));
context.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, myIntentFilter);

// place your BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity, your UploadData class
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyBroadcastReceiver(){
        super();
    }
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast received");
        if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(context.getString(R.string.broadcast_id)) ){
            // do something
        }
    }
}

// send Broadcasts from where you want to act, your UploadAct class.
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(context.getString(R.string.broadcast_id));
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast sent.");

// you can unregister this receiver in onDestroy() method
context.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: you need to register the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @rupinderjeet what is this: `<string name="broadcast_id">MY_BROADCAST_ID</string>`? and how and where to use this?

Comment: add this line in the `strings.xml` file under `res > values > strings.xml`. Then, we get `broadcast_id` from `context.getString(R.string.broadcast_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an interface to update your UI as a listener.

First, Create an interface

```
public interface UpdateTextListener {
    void updateText(String data);
}
```

Then, Call its method in your UploadData class

```
 public class UploadData extends UploadAct {

     UpdateTextListener listener;

     public void doSomethig(){
         listener.updateText("data to be loaded");
     }
 }
```

Then, Update your UploadAct by listening to this method

```
public class UploadAct extends MainActivity  implements UpdateTextListener {

     @Override
     public void updateText(String  data) {
         textview.setText(data);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - there is no such thing like UI of some class. There are activities that can have handles to UI widgets (ex TextView). If you want to make some changes to UI from your UploadData class you have to pass somehow reference to this class. Possibly by constructor:

```
public class UploadData extends UploadAct{
private TextView txt_upload;

public UploadData(TextView tv)
{
      txt_upload = tv;
}
public void doSomethig(){
printThis("I want to print this message to the UI")
}

 public void printThis(String messsage) {
    final String mess = message;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mess,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// I want this to display on the main thread
            txt_upload.setText(mess);// and this also
        }
    });
}
}
```

I assume that you create DataUpload in your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone use so much library to be trendy as they forget built in functions in Android :)

For sure isn't any hard thing to use `AsyncTask`, beside it provides the `doInBackground` function it has the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...) function too, what you have asked for.

Just create a class (UploadTask) which extends AsyncTask and override 1-2 function.