# .logEvent() is not logging the event in the FirebaseConsole

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm following this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) trying to log a `SIGN_UP` event when user sign up in my app.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD, "facebook");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SIGN_UP, bundle);
```

but nothing with the event name `sign_up` is getting shown in the Firebase Console.

Why is this happening?

P.S.: I haven't done the `Confirm Events` part as given at the bottom in the link I have provided above.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you please tell me why nothing appeared under the `value` column in FirebaseConsole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the Firebase Console (Analytics) aren't updated in realtime. You should wait (max 24 hours) before the data in the console is updated

Comment: Oh! Is that so? Okay then, I'll wait and respond back tomorrow.

Comment: hey, the event `sign_up` appeared in the console but the value i.e. `facebook` here is not getting shown and instead there is an empty space.

Comment: please respond, @Matt.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer. I don't use analytics currently so I'm not able to help

Comment: + can you accept this answer? This could help future developers with this problem

Comment: now can you do me a favour by helping with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41125004/6144372